# Google Appengine Reading text from TextProperty or BlobProperty line by line like a file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a Google Appengine Python project where users will upload a "csv type" file, which i can store in either a `TextProperty` or `BlobProperty` as they will be way under 1 mb.

What I can't figure out is how to read the file later from the blob, and process it line by line.

```
import csv

class Upload(db.Model):
    #file = db.TextProperty(verbose_name='Uploaded File', required=True)
    file = db.BlobProperty(verbose_name='Uploaded File', required=True)
    #  ...

    def ProcessCsv(self):
        csvReader = csv.reader(self.file,delimiter=',')
        for row in csvReader:
            print(', '.join(row))
```

print just prints out each character in the "file" on each line

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on is you are handing a string to csv.reader when it wants a file object or a list.

try: self.file.split('\n') to turn the string into a list of strings.

Comment: That's what I did, but I didn't think it was the right solution. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it's the perfect solution.  If the csv files get big it could be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You want a BlobReader, which is a file-like object for reading from a blob. You can get one by calling `.open()` on your BlobInfo object, like this:

```
f = self.file.open()
```